# Do any First Order pilots have red on their helmets?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, first-order

In [wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Order_TIE_Fighter_Pilot), the First Order Tie Fighter pilots *don't* have red on their helmets.

[image: pilot with all-black helmet]

However, *some* of the [toys](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TQYB2HG) show these weird red lines:

[image: toy with red marks]

I remember seeing red on the pilot's helmet in the film, but I assumed it was just a reflection of some kind. This belief was reenforced by the first image and the fact that some toys show it all black. I was therefore very surprised to see some toys had the red marking. **Do any First Order pilots have red on their helmets, or is this some kind of mistake in the toy coloring or something?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Only the elite special forces ones.

From the canonical [Star Wars databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/first-order-tie-fighter-pilots):

> Elite Special Forces fighter pilots bear red flashes on their helmets, and report to the upper ranks of the First Order hierarchy.

[image: image from Databank]

Comment: O.O Man, I was sure those red lines were just reflections, haha! Thanks. :)

Comment: @RedCaio - Would Hasbro lie to you? http://i2.wp.com/thefwoosh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Hasbro-Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens-First-Order-Special-Forces-TIE-Fighter-Pilot.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Not lie, but they tricked me. [My toy](http://theforceawakenstoys.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Cropped-image-1032x675.jpg) doesn't have any red on it. Mine must not be the "special" kind :/